# I want to create a flutter page that loads and plays videos stored in firebase storage

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-storage

I want to create a flutter page that loads and plays videos stored in firebase storage.

The way I know is how to call it with url through flutter video player like below.

```
    VideoPlayerController _controller;
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
    'firebase video url')
  ..initialize().then((_) {
    setState(() {});
  });
```

However, I don't know how to make a url to a file in firebase storage. I need a method in dart language.
Or is there any reference material?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to get the `downloadURL` of the file in Firebase Storage:

```
Future<void> downloadURLExample() async {
  String downloadURL = await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref('users/123/avatar.jpg')
      .getDownloadURL();

  // Within your widgets:
  // Image.network(downloadURL);
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#download-urls).

I would also recommend to get the `downloadURL` after you uploaded the file to Storage and save it somewhere in your Firebase database. That way when you read your post or article you have that `downloadURL` prepared for fast download. Getting the `downloadURL` is an `async` task and takes also some time to complete.